# Should I learn a cross-platform GUI language or go with a native?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform

Should I learn a cross-platform language that runs on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux, or just develop in a native GUI language? I heard that cross-platform is slower than native. Is it that much slower? And could you please recommend some GUI languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your final application. I think it's reasonable to say that the knowledge of a more flexible and cross-platform tool is much more valuable than another one that works only in a limited domain. 
I would suggest you to start with wxPython, works on every platform, is well tested and has all the widgets that you might need. Python is an interpreted language, so by definition is slower than other compiled languages, but the drawback in the execution speed is not even noticeable in most of applications.
Ah, and it's simple to learn.

Comment: Is python good for general-purpose programming?

Comment: Definitely. Is the fastest growing language: simple, elegant, easy to understand and maintain. There is a library ready for all your needs!

Comment: Should I learn python, or should I learn something more low-level like C++? I won't be developing games just apps that solve everyday problems.

Comment: Well I wouldn't define C++ "low level". The truth is, if you learn C/C++ you will prepared for any other language. Not to mention that they are faster the an interpreted language like Python. If you are passionate and eager to learn go for C++, if you are looking for a quick solution go for Python.

Comment: I have tried a little bit of python, and I think it's very nice. But it's a scripting language. How can it be used to create apps?

Comment: How do I download wxPython?

Comment: http://www.wxpython.org/download.php

Answer (score 0):

GUIs are not made with languages, they are made with toolkits. On proprietary operating systems, these will be integrated into the OS itself. On open source operating systems, they will be separate programs and thus inherently almost always cross-platform. For example, Qt and GTK+ will both run on all three of the biggest operating systems today. In theory, native GUIs should run faster on Windows and Mac OS X than cross-platform GUIs, but obviously that depends on a wide variety of factors. The opposite might be true.

Luckily, properly-programmed GUIs are almost never significant bottlenecks. You should consider whether various GUI toolkits have the features you want and what languages (especially ones you already know) they can be used in.

Comment: Thank you. What is your favorite GUI toolkit?

Comment: I'm still trying to decide myself, actually.

Comment: Qt vs GTK+ vs wx? Which is faster for python?

Comment: WX translates to native on Windows and OS X, and on Linux it uses GTK.

Comment: How do I download wxpython?

Comment: I can't hold your hand. If you want to be a programmer, then sooner or later you need to figure things out yourself. All day long.